# Signing CSR with Java does not validate using OpenSSL

Tags: java, openssl, certificate, bouncycastle, csr

I'm signing a CSR to an intermediate certificate, both of which were generated using OpenSSL. The signing code uses Java Bouncy Castle APIs, and the code successfully generates a cert. When inspecting the cert, everything appears fine. The issuer and other data show up correctly in the dump.

However, when executing an `openssl verify` command, it fails with:
`error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`

Signing an OpenSSL generated CSR to this same intermediate certificate verifies correctly.

The verify is successful when checked with the Java code:
`cert.verify(cacert.getPublicKey())`

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

```
public static X509Certificate certFromFile(String path) {
    X509Certificate cert;
    try {
        CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
        cert = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
    } catch (CertificateException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(error);
        return null;
    }
    return cert;
}

public static String DumpCert(X509Certificate cert) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        out.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".getBytes());
        out.write(Base64.encode(cert.getEncoded()));
        out.write("\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n".getBytes());
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException | CertificateEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    String certpem = null;
    try {
        certpem = new String(out.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return certpem;
}

public static ContentSigner createSigner(PrivateKey privateKey) {
    try {
        ContentSigner sig = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withECDSA").build(privateKey);
        return sig;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create content signer.", e);
    }
}

public static String signCSR(PKCS10CertificationRequest csr, GeneralName san, int validity,
                             X509Certificate cacert, KeyStore keystore, String alias) throws Exception {

    Date from = new Date();
    Date to = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (validity * 86400000L));

    PrivateKey cakey = null;
    try {
        cakey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    GeneralNames subjectAltNames = new GeneralNames(san);

    org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name csrSubject = csr.getSubject();
    X500Name issuer = new X500Name(cacert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    X500Name caName = X500Name.getInstance(PrincipalUtil.getIssuerX509Principal(cacert).getEncoded());

    GeneralNames gn = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(caName));

    BigInteger serial = new BigInteger(32, new SecureRandom());

    SubjectPublicKeyInfo keyinfo = csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();

    DigestCalculator digCalc = new BcDigestCalculatorProvider().get(new AlgorithmIdentifier(OIWObjectIdentifiers.idSHA1));
    X509ExtensionUtils x509ExtensionUtils = new X509ExtensionUtils(digCalc);

    X509v3CertificateBuilder certgen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serial, from, to, csrSubject, keyinfo);
    BigInteger serialcert = cacert.getSerialNumber();
    Boolean buildCACert = true;

    PublicKey caKey = cacert.getPublicKey();
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo keyinfoCA = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(caKey.getEncoded());

    AuthorityKeyIdentifier akiMain = x509ExtensionUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(keyinfoCA);
    AuthorityKeyIdentifier aki = new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(akiMain.getKeyIdentifier(), gn, serialcert);

    certgen.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, false, new BasicConstraints(buildCACert));
    certgen.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, x509ExtensionUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(keyinfo));
    certgen.addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, aki);
    certgen.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltNames);

    ContentSigner signer = createSigner(cakey);
    X509CertificateHolder holder = certgen.build(signer);

    X509Certificate cert = null;
    try {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(holder.getEncoded());
        cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
    } catch (CertificateException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return DumpCert(cert);
}

public static GeneralName getSubjectAlternativeName(PKCS10CertificationRequest csr) {
    org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute[] certAttributes = csr.getAttributes();
    for (org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute attribute : certAttributes) {
        if (attribute.getAttrType().equals(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest)) {
            Extensions extensions = Extensions.getInstance(attribute.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0));
            GeneralNames gns = GeneralNames.fromExtensions(extensions, Extension.subjectAlternativeName);
            GeneralName name = gns.getNames()[0];
            return name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static String PrepAndSignCSR(String raw_csr, String certPath, String keystore) {

    KeyStore ks = null;
    Object parsedObject = null;
    String alias = "alias";
    String s = null;
    X509Certificate caCert = null;

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(raw_csr);
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(sr);

    try {
        parsedObject = pemParser.readObject();
        System.out.println("PemParser returned : " + parsedObject);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(error);
    }

    PKCS10CertificationRequest CSR = (PKCS10CertificationRequest) parsedObject;
    caCert = certFromFile(certPath);

    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("ncipher.sworld", "nCipherKM");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystore);
        ks.load(in, null);
    } catch (KeyStoreException |
            NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            CertificateException |
            IOException |
            NoSuchProviderException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    GeneralName san = getSubjectAlternativeName(CSR);
    try {
        String cert = signCSR(CSR, san, 3500, caCert, ks, alias);
        return cert;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(error);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    .
    .
    .
    String fini = PrepAndSignCSR(csr, caCertPath, keystore);
    System.out.println(fini);

}
```

}

Comment: Since you solved it yourself, just a note: Instead of creating the PEM-block yourself, you can use PEMWriter. Strictly speaking your generated PEM-block is incorrect, because line breaks should be `\r\n` not just `\n`. Also you output the base64 data in one single line but there is a maximum length for the single line (don't remember the exact value)

Comment: @Lothar: the original (PEM) RFC said 64, the MIME RFC for base64 (but not PEM as such) said 76. OpenSSL writes 64 but before release 1.1.0 reads any multiple of 4 up to 76; release 1.1.0 can read up to about 1k. BC writes 64 but reads anything Java BufferedReader can handle (I believe 2G).

Answer (score 0):

After some debug sessions within openssl, I found the issuer name was not matching. Replaced this line with getEncoded...

     `X500Name issuer = newX500Name(cacert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
     X500Name issuer = X500Name.getInstance(cacert.getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded());`

The signed certs are now verifying with openssl verify command.

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

- `java.security.cert.Certificate.verify()` does nothing more than check the digital signature against the supplied public key.
- `openssl x509 verify` checks the entire certificate chain, looks for the trust anchor, and verifies the digital signature and expiry dates of every certificate in the chain.

You need to specify the `-CAfile` or `-CApath` options to `openssl`. See the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/verify.html).

Comment: In openssl verify, I'm using verify -CAfile intermediate.pem signed.pem

Comment: And does it have access to the root certificate?

Comment: Yes, the intermediate is a bundle containing root. I can sign other csr's using OpenSSL and it verifies correctly using the same bundle. There is something different when signed in Java. We're doing this in Java as we are using an HSM which doesn't have support for generating key pairs in OpenSSL.

Comment: Can you show us the Java code being used to sign the CSR?

Comment: I added the bulk of the Java signing code to original post.

Comment: I ran this into a debugging version of openssl, and it fails in the function X509_STORE_CTX_get_by_subject(...). If I pass in a good cert (signed in openssl to the same bundle) this function returns 1. The invalid cert returns 0. This function calls X509_OBJECT_retrieve_by_subject(...)